# ansible collections and AWX cloud.common module not found

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm using the ansible collection vmware.vmware_rest to clone a vm.  The collection requires cloud.common.  Everything works great if I run it via ansible-playbook, but when I try to run it in ansible tower (AAP), I get an error module not found, ansible_collections/cloud/common/plugins/plugins_utils/turbo.  The tower version has no problem finding vmware.vmware_rest or common.vmware, just can't find cloud.common.  This is a disconnected system.  Collections are in /usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections.

It errors out when I try to do a lookup on a datastore moid.  Lookup is in the collection cloud.common.
Is there a way to get tower to recognize the collection, cloud.common?
thanks

Comment: What are ansible and Tower versions? You said it's a disconnected system, I suppose that means it's not connected to internet, so how do you usually download collections?

Comment: It is Ansible Automation Platform, 2.1 with tower 4.x ( I believe) and ansible 2.9.  We have to sneaker net the collections. Download the tarball copy to DVD and copy to the AAP server.  AAP uses containers for execution environments and believe that is where the problem lays.